# Подключение к удаленному ip-адресу:порту как к внутреннему

Tags: linux, сеть

Приветствую!

Для примера: есть сервер `10.10.0.1` с открытым портом `3306`. На другом локальном компьютере, есть чудо-прога которая может подключатся только к `127.0.0.1` и порту `3306`.

Существует ли какая нибудь возможность, подключится к удаленному серверу как к локалхосту на то же порт?

Comment: при проброске портов с помощью ssh он как раз открывает локальные порты на 127.0.0.1

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/81607/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если верно понял

удаленный хост - 10.10.0.1:3306

```
~$ ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@10.10.0.1
```

будет проброшен тоннель, порт 3306  перенапрален и доступен локально.

Второй вариант

хост 10.10.0.1 доступен для хоста с чудо прогой

логинемся на чудо-хост и линкуем порты:

```
~$ ssh -L 3306:10.10.0.1:3306 localhost
```